# Smart Contract throwing reversion when called from frontend but fine when called from remix

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am facing an odd case where I am calling a view method in a smart contract with the correct address and ABI but am getting a reversion from the contract itself when it's being called through a library such as web3 from a frontend web application.

However, when trying on remix for example, with the same contract and method and parameters and address, the method is working.

Can anyone provide some insight into this?

Comment: Hi, can you show the code maybe?

Comment: The code cannot be shared sorry but it doesn't seem to be a code issue, that's why I'm confused as the contract method works when called through remix, for example

Comment: Glad you fixed the problem. Keep in mind people that use this website are not divinity and without showing a code (it does not need to be the whole code just the buggy part) we cannot help you. Also by providing  your code you might help others that come accross the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use `.call({from: userAddress})` instead of just `.call()`